# Помогите исправить ошибку в QT.

Tags: qt, c++, ubuntu

Здравствуйте!

Изучаю QT, и FFTW библиотеку. 
Есть проект, я его собираю в Ubuntu в QT 4.8.1.
Сперва я собирал его в Visual studio 10, но в Windows потоки меня не радуют( и решил перебраться в QT.
Вроде всё все пути к файлам заголовков прописал, но вылетают такие ошибки:

```
can not find -lfftw_threads
can not find -lfftw3
collect2: Id returnet 1 exit status.
```

Пошел на сайт библиотеки FFTW... так и не смог исправить эту ошибку(

Подскажите что может быть не так???
Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Заголовки тут не причем, падает линковщик - не может найти статические библиотеки с которыми он должен слинковать ваш экзешник. Найдите где у вас лежат соответствующие файлы (libfftw_threads.a и libfftw3.a, обычно они около сырцов в папке lib, иногда bin) и добавть в qt путь до них (LIBS+= в про файле насколько помню, но лучше уточните).

Также возможен вариант что вы выкачали библиотеку для студии, а собираете с помощью мингв, насколько помню у них разные форматы статических библиотек и друг друга они не понимают, хотя тогда сообщение было бы другое - у вас именно не нашлись либы

Comment: Этих библиотек нет(есть только для студии. Попробовал их вставить-не пошло.

Comment: естественно не пошло - формат разный, нужно либо найти\собрать версию для вашего компилятора (там вроде кроме mingw и быть ничего не может), либо скачать qt совместимый с вашей студией

Comment: Сейчас кручу-верчу на оф сайте FFTW, и не нахожу библиотеки под убунту. Или ее самому нужно компилировать из исходников?

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте в .pro файл:
LIBS += -lfftw_threads -lfftw3 -L<путь к папке с этими библиотекам>